# How to make machined plastic part slippery for small dry particles

Tags: friction, plastic

We have a plastic part that is a receptacle for small ( < 1mm ) particles. It is a disk with a shallow cone shaped indent made using a drill. When a particle is placed in the receptacle it should fall to the centre, but sometimes it stays on the side due to friction.

The particles can be spherical, globular or circular flat, and are made of calcium carbonate :) They are dropped in one by one and the slope of the cone is about 20 degrees.

To fix this, we are thinking the receptacle should be metal with teflon coating. However, is there any other coating we can apply to the plastic to increase its slipperiness? Perhaps rubbing graphite or a pencil lead in there?

Comment: Have you tried? what happened?

Comment: @SolarMike I haven't tried yet, the machine of which they are a part is still in operation for the next few hours. I will report back if it does work.

Comment: There are a lot of questions: What material are the particles made of? What shape are the particles - are they spherical, flat, jagged? do you place one particle through the funnel at a time, or a whole stream of particles?

Comment: From your description, it sounds more like static electricity than friction keeping the particle from falling through the funnel

Comment: @CharlPretorius Updated with answers. Static electricity could be one problem.

Comment: A grounded metal slope (non coated) would remove static. Surface finish is as likely to be as important as the actual frictional properties of the material

Comment: @JonathanRSwift The receptacle has to be as dark as possible. Would a thin layer of paint remove the anti-static nature of the metal?

Comment: If you need darkness, consider anodized aluminum

Comment: @geometrikal - it depends if the static buildup (if indeed that's the current problem) is coming from the movement of particles on the surface, or some other source. Most paint ([and most anodising!](https://www.techbriefs.com/component/content/article/tb/techbriefs/materials/1159)) is insulating, and as such would allow a build of static. [conductive paint does exist](https://www.bareconductive.com/shop/electric-paint-10ml/), but I don't know what the surface properties of this are

Comment: I'm thinking a highly polished aluminum receptacle that is hard coat anodized black, and then coated with a good anti-static spray , then electrically ground the assembly.